# NPM is giving me an Error with every command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, registry

Whenever I'm running a command with npm. it's giving an Error. A few days ago, It was totally fine. I used it in some of my projects but now it is can't do nothing.

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

    Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\nuur hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js
    - C:\Users\nuur hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
    - C:\Users\nuur hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nuur hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js:2:19)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [
        'C:\\Users\\nuur hassan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\unsupported.js',
        'C:\\Users\\nuur hassan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
        'C:\\Users\\nuur hassan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your installation got corrupted. I'd wipe it and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that npm can't find the package.json file. Make sure you haven't deleted it. If you want to create one you can use npm init to initialize one in the current directory. Even if that fails I'd reinstall node js and double check the NODE_PATH.